# Get key and value & key and object with reduce function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, reduce

I have below data from my API call and I am working with reduce function to set data as per my requirement. But not able to produce it, please check below code and required output. Also check the function I am trying and suggest me way to create the response.

*API Response:*

```
let cmpRecords =  {
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Record Fetched Successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e",
            "record": {
                "creatorName": "ABC",
                "modifierName": ""
            },
            "is_deleted": "0"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e",
            "record": {
                "creatorName": "ABC",
                "modifierName": ""
            },
            "is_deleted": "0"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6z",
            "record": {
                "creatorName": "XYZ",
                "modifierName": ""
            },
            "is_deleted": "0"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

*Required Output ::*

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Record Fetched Successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "record": [
                {
                    "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e",
                    "record": {
                        "creatorName": "ABC",
                        "modifierName": ""
                    },
                    "is_deleted": "0"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e",
                    "record": {
                        "creatorName": "ABC",
                        "modifierName": ""
                    },
                    "is_deleted": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "record": [
                {
                    "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6z",
                    "record": {
                        "creatorName": "XYZ",
                        "modifierName": ""
                    },
                    "is_deleted": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As I want to seperate record of same user, with key and value & key and object I used reduce function for this

```
group = cmpRecords.reduce((r, a) => {
    let name = a.record.creatorName;
    let record = a;

    r[name] = [...r[name] || [], record];

    return r;
}, {});
```

This responds with

```
"data": [
    "ABC":[
        {
            "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e",
            "record": {
                "creatorName": "ABC",
                "modifierName": ""
            },
            "is_deleted": "0"
        },
        ...
    ]
]
```

I tried other ways but not getting required response.

Comment: In your output, `data` should be an array of Objects where each would have both `name` and `record` as attributes.

Comment: @pistou Yes, I actually created response manually so I missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to group your records by name, the output here should be what you require:

```js
        
const cmpRecords =  { "status": "success", "message": "Record Fetched Successfully", "data": [ { "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e", "record": { "creatorName": "ABC", "modifierName": "" }, "is_deleted": "0" }, { "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6e", "record": { "creatorName": "ABC", "modifierName": "" }, "is_deleted": "0" }, { "_id": "6098ff60a8e9ee2c7c116d6z", "record": { "creatorName": "XYZ", "modifierName": "" }, "is_deleted": "0" }, ] }

const output = {
    ...cmpRecords,
    data: Object.values(cmpRecords.data.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
        acc[cur.record.creatorName] = acc[cur.record.creatorName] || { name: cur.record.creatorName, record: [] };
        acc[cur.record.creatorName].record.push(cur);
        return acc;
    }, {}))
}

console.log('Output:', output)
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!